# Android: Stop playback on Home or Back button

Tags: android, android-homebutton

When I press back or home in my application, it hides, but the MediaPlayer keeps going. Is there a way to know when these buttons have been pressed and stop playback before closing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to override the `onPause()` function in your `Activity`. `onPause()` will be called when you `Activity` is hidden and you can pause the `MediaPlayer` there.

For example,

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause(); // Don't forget this line
    myMediaPlayer.pause() // Or whatever the function is to pause it
}
```

Comment: @Joel Can you provide more details, such as a stack trace?

Comment: I'm now not totally sure that this was what was causing the crash. Let me get back to you...

Answer (score 3):

just implement this method in your class where media player is calling...

```
@Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) 
    {
        if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)) 
        { //Back key pressed
           //Things to Do
            if(mediaPlayer!= null)
            {
                mediaPlayer.stop();
                mediaPlayer=null;
            }
            finish();
            return true;
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget to add super.onPause; if you forget it will cause a FC.